# ¿Cómo corregir este problema con los permisos de usuario en Batch?

Tags: cmd, batch, permisos

soy algo nuevo con la programación batch, y estoy creando un pequeño proyecto para hacerme unas tareas mas fáciles jeje, he creado un menú con opciones, la cual una de ellas otorgar permisos o cambiar de grupo a un usuario (ingresado manualmente), es decir, si el usuario es admin, cambiarlo a usuario estándar y viceversa, pero por alguna razon al seleccionar la opcion me cierra la ventana `cmd`.

Quizas me equivoque en algo basico, pero estoy empezando, este es mi código:

```
    :op3
      echo.
      echo.
      "PERMISOS DE USUARIOS"
      echo.
        SET /p user= ^>Escribe el nombre de usuario:
        net localgroup Usuarios %user% /add
      echo.
      pause
    goto:inicio
```

desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta el .bat en modo administrador, alli no deberia darte problemas

Comment: no, tenia un error muy tonto jaja, era que el :op3 tenia que remplazarlo como op4 jaja